# Makefile : --ignore-errors vs --keep-going

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I was going through [Makefile documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html), I am not clear of the difference between `--ignore-errors` and `--keep-going`.

Can someone please highlight the difference between the two? To me, both seem to continue after an error has occured.

Though its not clear from documentation, but `--ignore-errors` could have recipe-level scope and if one recipe line has failed, next one will continue to execute. `--keep-going` may have target-level scope and if any target recipe fails, the recipe execution ends there, but other prerequisites/targets will still be attempted to make. This is just a possible perception and need clarification on this.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Errors

> Sometimes the failure of a certain recipe line does not indicate a problem. For example, you may use the `mkdir` command to ensure that a directory exists. If the directory already exists, `mkdir` will report an error, but you probably want `make` to continue regardless.
>
> To ignore errors in a recipe line, write a `-` at the beginning of the line’s text (after the initial tab). The `-` is discarded before the line is passed to the shell for execution.
>
> For example,
>
> ```
> clean:
>         -rm -f *.o
> ```
>
> This causes `make` to continue even if `rm` is unable to remove a file.
>
> When you run `make` with the `-i` or `--ignore-errors` flag, errors are ignored in all recipes of all rules. A rule in the makefile for the special target `.IGNORE` has the same effect, if there are no prerequisites. These ways of ignoring errors are obsolete because `-` is more flexible.

In other words, `make --ignore-errors` behaves like there is a `-` in front of all commands.

> When errors are to be ignored, because of either a `-` or the `-i` flag, `make` treats an error return just like success, except that it prints out a message that tells you the status code the shell exited with, and says that the error has been ignored.
>
> When an error happens that `make` has not been told to ignore, it implies that the current target cannot be correctly remade, and neither can any other that depends on it either directly or indirectly. No further recipes will be executed for these targets, since their preconditions have not been achieved.
>
> Normally make gives up immediately in this circumstance, returning a nonzero status. However, if the `-k` or `--keep-going` flag is specified, `make` continues to consider the other prerequisites of the pending targets, remaking them if necessary, before it gives up and returns nonzero status. For example, after an error in compiling one object file, `make -k` will continue compiling other object files even though it already knows that linking them will be impossible. See [Summary of Options](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Options-Summary).
>
> The usual behavior assumes that your purpose is to get the specified targets up to date; once `make` learns that this is impossible, it might as well report the failure immediately. The `-k` option says that the real purpose is to test as many of the changes made in the program as possible, perhaps to find several independent problems so that you can correct them all before the next attempt to compile. This is why Emacs’ `compile` command passes the `-k` flag by default.

Let's take this example:

```
target: intermediate-1 intermediate-2 intermediate-3
        cat intermediate-1 intermediate-2 intermediate-3 > target

intermediate-1:
        echo "oh no, I'm failing!"
        false

intermediate-2:
        echo 'hello' > intermediate-2

intermediate-3:
        echo 'world' > intermediate-3
```

Normally when you run `make target` (and none of the files exist yet), it will first try to make `intermediate-1`. That target fails because one of the associated commands (`false`) returns a non-zero exit status. `make` then immediately gives up and does not even look at `intermediate-2` or `intermediate-3`.

However, with `make --keep-going target`, it will note the failure of `intermediate-1`, but keep on going to make `intermediate-2` and `intermediate-3`, which succeeds (creating files containing "hello" and "world", respectively).

In the end it still gives up and reports a failure to make `target`, but it has tried to create all intermediate targets, even ones it knows won't be used in this run of `make` because another prerequisite already failed.

If you use both flags (`make --ignore-errors --keep-going`), then `--keep-going` is effectively ignored. `--keep-going` only affects how `make` behaves when it encounters an error in an intermediate target, but `--ignore-errors` means `make` will never encounter an error.

Comment: Fantastic answer and at least the first part of the answer is still working in 2022, thank you!